# cannot create a spring template project using STS

Tags: spring

While creating a new spring template project, I keep getting the following error -

```
Input for field toplevelpackage does not match the regex \w+\.\w+(\.\w+)+.
```

I tried all combinations for top level package names. But none seem to work

```
com.springtest
com.springtest.*
com.springtest*
```

We cant leave this field empty. :-(
I am using STS version of 2.9.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define a top package name with 3 or more parts.

for example

```
com.mycompany.myapp
```

*BTW: That is exact what the regex and the example in the dialog say*

Comment: worked.thanks. but i wonder why they have this restriction of 3 levels or more...